# Hello world kernel module for android & unknown relocation: 27 when insmod

Tags: android, module, linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module

I am trying to create a simple kernel module.
I am trying to print messages to dmesg but i keep getting

insmod: init_module 'hello.ko' failed (Exec format error) in android

after :
dmesg:
unknown relocation: 27

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kdb.h>
int init_module(void)
{
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Hello world!\n");
    return 1;
}

void cleanup_module(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Goodbye world 1.\n");
}
MODULE_AUTHOR("Robert P. J. Day");
MODULE_LICENSE("Dual BSD/GPL");
MODULE_VERSION("2:1.0") ;
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("You have to start somewhere.");
```

The make file

```
    obj-m +=hello.o


KERNELDIR ?= ~/android/kernel/common
#KERNELDIR ?= /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
PWD := $(shell pwd)
CROSS_COMPILE=~/android-ndk-r8/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-

ARCH=arm
default:
$(MAKE) -C $(KERNELDIR) M=$(PWD) ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=$(CROSS_COMPILE) modules

clean:
$(MAKE) -C $(KERNELDIR) M=$(PWD) clean
rm *.symvers
```

does anyone know why? And how to get it working?

I found after doing a readelf that when it is compiled the relocation section is pointing to the wrong directions.

```
Offset     Info    Type            Sym.Value  Sym. Name
00000008  0000171b R_ARM_PLT32       00000000   printk
```

When in fact it should be:

```
Offset     Info    Type            Sym.Value  Sym. Name
00000008  0000171c R_ARM_CALL       00000000   printk
```

Can someone guess/know how this might be?
Thanks @Chris Stratton for helping me this far.

---

I found after doing a readelf that when it is compiled the relocation section is pointing to the wrong directions.

```
Offset     Info    Type            Sym.Value  Sym. Name
00000008  0000171b R_ARM_PLT32       00000000   printk
```

When in fact it should be:

```
Offset     Info    Type            Sym.Value  Sym. Name
00000008  0000171c R_ARM_CALL       00000000   printk
```

Can someone guess/know how this might be? Thanks @Chris Stratton for helping me this far.

Comment: Probably a build system problem.  Are you sure you can use the ndk toolchain for a kernel?  My recollection is that you could not in the past, but maybe that has changed.  Could be worthwhile to objdump/readelf your module vs. any working one you can find and look at the types of relocations.

Comment: I think we've got a lead.The difference i found when performing readelf was Flag was "0x5000000, Version5 EABI" for a running module and Flag is "0x4000000, Version4 EABI" for my module. Does this affect anything? I cannot find any place to change it. I am searching for it. If anyone knows please let me know.

Comment: It seems EABIs are backwards compatible so I was heading in the wrong direction there for a while.

Comment: Now I find that in my hello world module

Relocation section '.rel.text' at offset 0x6b8 contains 4 entries:
 Offset     Info    Type            Sym.Value  Sym. Name
00000008  0000211b R_ARM_PLT32       00000000   printk

whereas in the wifimodule
00001c4c  000d421c R_ARM_CALL        00000000   printk

Comment: Yes it is the wrong relocation. If I change hex through the hex editor from R_ARM_PLT32(1B) to R_ARM_CALL(1C) it goes and stops in another relocation error. Can someone guess what I might be doing wrong to get wrong relocations?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It turns out I had to use

```
make CFLAGS_MODULE=-fno-pic
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, -fno-pic got my dlkm working also.  On to "real" work...

BTW, you can export ARCH, SUBARCH, CROSS_COMPILE, KERNELDIR in the shell so the Makefile becomes very simple.  This also allows one to more easily build the dlkm for the native or target platform by setting the KERNELDIR properly (native does not need the ARCH, SUBARCH or CROSS_COMPILE vars.)

obj-m += hello.o

all:
    make -C $(KERNELDIR) M=$(PWD) modules