# Why compile Android kernel module with -fno-pic?

Tags: android, linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module

I often read that Android kernel modules have to be compiled with `-fno-pic` to work. Is this specific to the ARM architecture, or why don't/(when do) kernel modules for x86 need to be compiled with that flag?

Comment: This post will states clearly :-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11614441/hello-world-kernel-module-for-android-unknown-relocation-27-when-insmod?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

According to https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-6.1.0/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html, `-fno-pic` is the negative form of the `-fpic` parameter. From the same link:

> -fpic Generate position-independent code (PIC) suitable for use in a shared library, if supported for the target machine. Such code
>   accesses all constant addresses through a global offset table (GOT).
>   The dynamic loader resolves the GOT entries when the program starts
>   (the dynamic loader is not part of GCC; it is part of the operating
>   system). If the GOT size for the linked executable exceeds a
>   machine-specific maximum size, you get an error message from the
>   linker indicating that -fpic does not work; in that case, recompile
>   with -fPIC instead. (These maximums are 8k on the SPARC, 28k on
>   AArch64 and 32k on the m68k and RS/6000. The x86 has no such limit.)
>   **Position-independent code requires special support, and therefore
>   works only on certain machines.** For the x86, GCC supports PIC for
>   System V but not for the Sun 386i. Code generated for the IBM RS/6000
>   is always position-independent.
>
> When this flag is set, the macros `__pic__` and `__PIC__` are defined to
>   1.

So `-fno-pic` means something like "Do **not** use position-independent code (PIC)."

But why?

Well, by looking at https://developer.arm.com/products/software-development-tools/hpc/documentation/note-about-building-position-independent-code-pic-on-aarch64, we find that:

> Using the -fpic compiler flag with GCC compilers on AArch64 causes the
>   compiler to generate one less instruction per address computation in
>   the code, and can provide code size and performance benefits. However,
>   it also sets a limit of 32k for the Global Offset Table (GOT), and the
>   build can fail at the executable linking stage because the GOT
>   overflows.

So, in the end, it seems like `-fno-pic` is more of a precaution than a real need. This, of course, is a guess and there might be more things involved.